# Pattern for initialization of subclasses

Tags: java

**Situation**

I have a class `Child`, it is a subclass of a `Parent`. Both access a member `number`. It looks like this:

Parent.java

```
public abstract class Parent {

    int number = 1;

    public Parent() {

        init1();

        System.out.println("parent:" + this);

        init2();

    }

    public abstract void init1();

    public void init2() {
        System.out.println("init2: " + number);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(number);
    }

}
```

Child.java

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    public Child() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void init1() {
        number = 2;
    }

}
```

**Problem**

I need to change the value of `number`, so that it is different in the constructor flow of Parent. Obvious solutions are:

- provide `number` in the constructor of `Parent` and set it there. But the problem is that there can be a lot of initialization values, so the method signature can become huge. I rather prefer to have default values in `Parent` instead of having to extend e.g. the constructor of Parent and hand over default parameters from every subclass. And I also don't want a number of different constructors, each with default values.
- set number in `init()` of `Child`. Here's the problem that the `Child` *must know* that it has to do something in `init()` instead of the constructor. Having to know something in a subclass is never good.

**Question**

Is there a better approach or pattern for this kind of problem instead of e.g. using an abstract class?

Comment: If you're worried about huge methods, you can separate them - methods call methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest that comes to my mind is requiring a single `Options` paramenter in the `Parent` constructor and set default values in that options type:

```
public class Parent {
  public Parent(Options options) {
    // ...
  }
}

// Default values set here
public class Options {
  public int someInt = 42;
  public String someString = "Hello world!";
}
```

Comment: I can't change Options before I call the Parent constructor from Child. Same problem. e. g. I need options.someInt to be 1 during the constructor flow of parent.

Comment: Why you think you can't? Use a static field or subclass `Options`